# Blender crashes instantly when entering (GL_INVALID_ENUM : Cubemap Workaround Start)

Tags: error

I was trying to use Blender for the first time, but when I try entering Blender, it stays in a gray screen for 15-20 seconds and closes (there is no "Blender is not responding" message, it just closes). I tried using  blender_debug_gpu and I got a txt file, "blender_debug_output" with "ERROR (gpu.debug):  : GL_INVALID_ENUM : Cubemap Workaround Start". The other day when I tried entering, I got another txt file but it said "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION".
Fyi, my gpu is Intel HD Graphics 5500.

Comment: There are no Blender developers here, nor does anyone here work for or have any association with the Blender Foundation. You haven't said what version of Blender you are using, but if your [system is supported](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) you should submit a [bug report](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports).